# Read file into two hashes with Perl

Tags: perl

I'm struggling to understand how to read a simple text file into two Perl hashes.

I have a text file like:

```
George Washington
John Adams
Abraham Lincoln
```

and I want to create two hashes, one that holds the first names and the other that holds the last names.

I'm looking at doing something like:

```
my %first;
my %last;
open(my $FH, '<', $file) or die$!;
my $count = 1;
while (<$FH>)
{
  chomp;
  if count is odd, add to %first
    elsif count is even, add to %last
}
close($FH);
```

but I'm honestly lost. Does anyone have any ideas?

---

Comment: Hint: `split` is your friend

Comment: Can `split` the line, and parse the obtained list; that'd be a direct answer to what's asked.  But ... the first element is the first name and the second one ... wait, what if there's more than two words?  You're in the complex business of parsing names.  Perhaps use a library?

Comment: John Quincy Adams, natch.

Comment: Would `($first, $last) = split(' ', $_, 2);` be on the right track?

Comment: what do you want in the hashes?  what are the keys and what are the values?

Comment: The keys should be names and values integers so later I can look up a corresponding first or last name when I pass the other.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. An integer isn't going to you help look up an element in a hash keyed by a name. Please clarify

Comment: Storing related data in two separate data structures is a terrible idea. Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get desired result with following code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $count = 0;
my %first;
my %last;

while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my($f,$l) = split;
    $first{$f} = $count;
    $last{$l} = $count;
    $count++;
}

say Dumper(\%first);
say Dumper(\%last);


__DATA__
George Washington
John Adams
Abraham Lincoln
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'George' => 0,
          'Abraham' => 2,
          'John' => 1
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'Adams' => 1,
          'Lincoln' => 2,
          'Washington' => 0
        };
```